# Wireless router configured as AP using dd-wrt drops packets

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I am using a new D-Link DIR-825 flashed with dd-wrt v24preSP2 build 18024.

The router is set up as an Access Point (AP) simply extending the network. We have used [this guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) to set it up.

The router seems to drop packets. We need to reload pages when browsing the net, and outlook connections are going up and down. The problem seems to be the same on both android phones, iphones and osx laptops. On my windows 7 machine I don't seem to have the same problem, but the network feels somewhat slower when browsing.

I don't know if it's relevant but my networks speeds are as follows:
With cable I get close to 94 Mbit/s downstream 11 Mbit/s upstream.
Wireless I get 19Mbit/s downstream 11 Mbit/s upstream.

How can I troubleshoot the router?

Comment: Honestly, my suggestion would be to try a non-jail broken router of the same model and see if you have the same problems. As it stands, this qualifies as "homebrew" in my book and is probably not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @joeqwerty The router couldn't by default work as a pure AP, hence I can't test it with default firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Being a bit biased by the recent blog posts on SF i'd suggest first reading the last two posts. [Approach at Wifi 1](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/12/12/a-studied-approach-at-wifi-part-1/) [Approach at Wifi 2](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/01/05/a-studied-approach-at-wifi-part-2/) i.e. first getting an idea about your wifi coverage and then you can move on and troubleshoot your router. Moreover
please do post more information like how do you get these "networks speeds" metrics.
Can you say for sure that it's OS dependent only?

Do some scanning on the area and find out when and where your signal drops. Once you are confident that your wifi coverage is OK move on to the router's conf.

P.S. packages != packets

EDIT 1: Come to think of it after joeqwerty's comment, your question indeed might not be fit for SF since if you are using firmware not supported by the vendor in your enterprise
well you are asking for it, but I can't see a reason why you'd jailbreak a router
at your work place (corner cases excluded).

Comment: Edited title and question. Replaced packages with packets. :)

Comment: The network speeds were obtained by using www.bredbandskollen.se

The signal doesn't drop at all, we are sitting in an open office and just 7 meters from the router. Also the signal is confirmed with Wifi Analyzer in android and we are using an empty channel.

Comment: The router was "jailbraked" because it din't work as a pure AP out of the box. Here's some other guys using upgraded routers at work: http://serverfault.com/questions/32999/does-anyone-use-dd-wrt-openwrt-etc-at-their-office

Answer (score 0):

You have provided too little useful information. The first thing you need to do is check the signal strength and find out what other APs are broadcasting. You can do this in ddwrt by going into Status->Wireless. It would be helpful if you could provide a screenshot. Next, click "Site survey" and take a screenshot of that as well.

Comment: The signal doesn't drop at all, we are sitting in an open office and just 7 meters from the router. Also the signal is confirmed with Wifi Analyzer in android and we are using an empty channel.

Comment: The signal doesn't drop from what? Please provide values in dB (decibels) or preferably screenshots.

Comment: The signal varies between -48 and -70 dBm, but usually better than -60. The "free surf" in this building is between -80 and -90 and works better than our router. What I'm trying to say is that I think the problem is not the wireless transmission but rather in the forwarding of packets within the router.